# Rename Column Depending on Value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table likeso:

```
Roll    Name    Type
3       Mark    Ultimate Internet
1       Ana     Chase
4       June    Ultimate Internet
2       Badol   Chase
```

How can I make a SELECT statement where I rename the "Type" column depending on a value? Something like:

```
SELECT Roll, Name,
    IF Type = 'Ultimate Internet' AS 'ISP' END IF
    IF Type = 'Chase' AS 'Bank' END IF
FROM MyTable
```

If Type = 'Ultimate Internet', the result would be:

```
Roll    Name    ISP
3       Mark    Ultimate Internet
4       June    Ultimate Internet
```

If Type = 'Chase', the result would be:

```
Roll    Name    Bank
1       Ana     Chase
2       Badol   Chase
```

Comment: you could migrate your `Type` column to two columns: `ISP` and `Bank`

Comment: `SELECT Roll, Name, type as ISP, '' as Bank
FROM MyTable
where Type = 'Ultimate Internet'
union all
SELECT Roll, Name, '' as ISP, type as Bank
FROM MyTable
where Type = 'Chase';` not tested, since there is no reproducible example

Comment: alternatively, you can do something like this: `SELECT Roll, Name, 
    if type = 'Ultimate Internet' type else '' as ISP, 
    if type = 'Chase' type else '' as Bank
FROM MyTable`

Comment: The context is very important for dynamic SQL situations. Can the column names be handled by your application (easy), can your application use a PL/SQL function or procedure that returns a dynamic ref cursor with the right column names (a little complicated), or does this need to be done in a single SQL statement (possible but very complicated)?

Answer (score 0):

No, because column names have to be known at compile time.

I am having trouble understanding what you're doing. You use `Type` as both a column name and a variable at the same time? Is this in PL/SQL? If so, you could have two different cursors, but then you're not displaying the output like this. If this is pure SQL, then where is the variable coming from?

Answer (score 0):

The column names need to be static. Instead of trying to dynamically build a single query, you can use two queries:

```sql
SELECT Roll, Name, type AS ISP
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  type = 'Ultimate Internet'
```

and:

```sql
SELECT Roll, Name, type AS bank
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  type = 'Chase'
```

---

You could even create a lookup table with the type values:

```sql
CREATE TABLE types (
  type       VARCHAR2(20) PRIMARY KEY,
  super_type VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO types (type, super_type)
SELECT 'Ultimate Internet', 'ISP'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Chase',             'bank' FROM DUAL;
```

and then use:

```sql
SELECT m.Roll, m.Name, m.type AS ISP
FROM   MyTable m
       INNER JOIN types t
       ON (m.type = t.type)
WHERE  t.super_type = 'ISP'
```

or

```sql
SELECT m.Roll, m.Name, m.type AS bank
FROM   MyTable m
       INNER JOIN types t
       ON (m.type = t.type)
WHERE  t.super_type = 'bank'
```